# How to trigger error callback in node.js (jasmine)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test error callback for s3 putObject function with node.js typescript, and jasmine karma for unit tests.

```
@Service()
export class S3Service {
    @Inject()
    private s3: S3;

      async upload(params: any) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.s3.putObject(params, ((error: any) => {
                if (error) {           // I want to test this statement
                    throw error;
                } else {
                    resolve('example');
                }
            }));
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my unit test. From now I am creating new Error object and passing it into callback function in mocked callFake function.

```
    it ('s3 trigger error callback', async () => {
        const params = {
            Bucket: example,
            Key: example,
            ContentType: example,
            Body: example,
            ACL: example
        };

        let s3 = Container.get(S3);
        const err: any = new Error('Triggered error string');

        spyOn(s3, 'putObject').and.callFake((param: any, fn: any ) => fn(err));

        await Container.get(S3Service).upload(params);

        expect(s3.putObject).toThrowError(err);
    });
```

The result from test is:
*Failures:
1)  S3Service s3 trigger error callback
  Message:
    Error: Triggered error string
  Stack:
    Error: Triggered error string*

How to trigger the error callback correctly?